# How do I install Ubuntu if my computer gets stuck at the bootup screen?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I'm trying to install ubuntu on my Hp Pavillion 13 with AMD Ryzen 500 and AMD Radeon Graphics.

I created a bootable USB drive that works on my other hp laptop using rufus.

When I bootup the usb, the following screen appears and I get stuck on it forever :
[loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D8fP.jpg)

And this is what is happening in the background : [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvCPH.jpg)

After I enter the grub and add nomode set, it gets stuck for 15 min on [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckv1d.jpg)

Them it keeps going, freezes and the screen turns off.

I tried replacing quiet splash bu no mode set and adding nomode set, no success.
I really need it to work

Edit:I am trying to dual boot

Comment: on the second image it says "Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting.)" What about that?

Comment: You can try to use <kdb>[ventoy](https://github.com/ventoy/Ventoy)</kdb>.
Also, have you tried to install other distros? Are they works? If only Ubuntu didn't work it might be installer bug I think

Comment: Your computer gets stuck at the bootup screen because, as @Andra pointed out, you did not complete your preparation to install Ubuntu. That trips up a lot of new users. Blame Windows for making it hard, it wasn't our decision. The answer to your direct question is that Operating Systems cannot be uninstalled. They get overwritten by the next OS installer.

Comment: @user535733 Hey, Thamks for your comment. I am trying to dual boot windows and ubuntu, do you know what steps I can take from the current point I'm stuck at?

Comment: My opinion is that your best option is an entirely new question, since your current question is about removing Ubuntu entirely.